# Non maximized browser messes up background image

Tags: javascript, css, background-image

I'm attempting to create a full screen changeable background image. I've spent a long time perfecting it to work on other PC's. It works perfectly on my screen, but on other monitors it changes.

The problem now is that the image is all over the place if the browser is not maximized. 
It works fine once maximized.

The background image changes every 5 seconds, so it's not as simple as just setting the background image. Here is my code:

```
<head>
<script type='text/javascript'>
var imageID=0;
function changeimage(every_seconds)
{
    //change the image
    if(!imageID)
    {
        document.getElementById("myimage").src="Minecraft.jpg";
        imageID++;
    }
    else if(imageID==1)
    {
        document.getElementById("myimage").src="Minecraft1.jpg";
        imageID++;
    }
    else if(imageID==2)
    {
        document.getElementById("myimage").src="Minecraft2.jpg";
        imageID++;
    }
    else if(imageID==3)
    {
        document.getElementById("myimage").src="Minecraft4.jpg";
        imageID++;
    }
    else if(imageID==4)
    {
        document.getElementById("myimage").src="Minecraft5.jpg";
        imageID++;
    }
    else if(imageID==5)
    {
        document.getElementById("myimage").src="Minecraft6.jpg";
        imageID++;
    }
    else if(imageID==6)
    {
        document.getElementById("myimage").src="Minecraft7.jpg";
        imageID=0;
    }
    //call same function again for x of seconds
    setTimeout("changeimage("+every_seconds+")",((every_seconds)*3000));
}
</script>

<style>
#myimage {
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
</style>

<body>
<body style='background:black; '
  onload='changeimage(2)'>
<div style='position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;left:0px;top:0px;' align='center'><img  id='myimage' src='Minecraft.jpg'/>
</div>
</body>
```

----------Edit--------------
I used your code (Hopefully correctly) but now the image isn't loading at all.

```
<head>
<script type='text/javascript'>
var imageID=0;
function changeimage(every_seconds)
{
    //change the image
    if(!imageID)
    {
        document.getElementByTagName("body").className="pic1";
        imageID++;
    }
    else if(imageID==1)
    {
        document.getElementByTagName("body").className="pic2";
        imageID++;
    }
    else if(imageID==2)
    {
       document.getElementByTagName("body").className="pic3";
        imageID++;
    }
    else if(imageID==3)
    {
        document.getElementByTagName("body").className="pic4";
        imageID++;
    }
    else if(imageID==4)
    {
        document.getElementByTagName("body").className="pic5";
        imageID++;
    }
    else if(imageID==5)
    {
        document.getElementByTagName("body").className="pic6";
        imageID++;
    }
    else if(imageID==6)
    {
        document.getElementByTagName("body").className="pic7";
        imageID=0;
    }
    //call same function again for x of seconds
    setTimeout("changeimage("+every_seconds+")",((every_seconds)*3000));
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<body>
<style>
.pic1 { background-image: 'Minecraft.jpg'; }
.pic2 { background-image: 'Minecraft1.jpg'; }
.pic3 { background-image: 'Minecraft2.jpg'; }
.pic4 { background-image: 'Minecraft5.jpg'; }
.pic5 { background-image: 'Minecraft6.jpg'; }
.pic6 { background-image: 'Minecraft7.jpg'; }
</style>

<body style='background:black; '
  onload='changeimage(2)'>
<div style='position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;left:0px;top:0px;' align='center'><img  id='myimage' src='Minecrft.jpg'/>
</div>
</body>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your style says well, that the image must spread over the whole screen. Adjust you styles according to your wishes.

Comment: That wasn't helpful at all :P I just need the browser to stop messing up the sizes/positioning.

Comment: I'm going to need more details to answer that.. Please upload a screenshot of the problem, and add your CSS and HTML codes that apply here.

Comment: You can see yourself by visiting http://evolutionhost.co.uk/GameOffers/Minecraft/Minecraft.php

Take the browser off it's max size and mess about with the scroll and re-size it.

Comment: Unrelated, but why not document.getElementById("myimage").src="Minecraft" + imageID + ".jpg";

Comment: Another unrelated suggestion: if you load all of the images on page load and hide all but one of them, then you can have smooth transitions between images. You could even use CSS animation to do fade transitions.

Answer (score 1):

Using a 100% x 100% absolutely positioned div for your background image is probably what's causing the issue.

Switch to CSS classes on < body >

```
.pic1 { background-image: '../path/to/image1'; }
.pic2 { background-image: '../path/to/image1'; }
etc
```

And then instead of changing the src of the image tag you would change the class of < body >.  This will allow you to remove the absolute positioning of that div and layout the site "normally".

Comment: How can I intregrate that with the lines like this?
document.getElementById("myimage").src="Minecraft.jpg";

Comment: document.getElementByTagName("body").className="newClassNameGoesHere";

Comment: I edited my original post. Thanks for your help by the way. Hopefully you can help me finalize this once and for all!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
var imageClass = 'pic';
if(imageID) {
    imageClass += imageID;
}
document.body.className = imageClass;
imageID++;
```

And CSS:

```
.pic {background-image: url(Minecraft.jpg);}
.pic1 {background-image: url(Minecraft1.jpg);}
```

etc.

To resize the background, you can choose the [CSS alternative](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background), which best fits to your site, for example:

```
body {
    background-position: 50% 0%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover cover;
}
```

[A live demo at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/myx4P/).